# Socket emit in a loop delays server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

i was checking out the simple node js & sockets chat model, and i've made a little change - when the user creates a socket connection with the server, he emits 250,000 message events. the server should respond by sending all the other participants those messages, and it works. 
the problem is that for some reason, only after the first user finish to send all the 250,000 message, the other users gets the first message. 
the wanted result is some kind of parallel execution of both the user and server.

i've used localhost/3000, and chrome developer console to make those tests.
any ideas?
thanks.

server.js:

```
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function (socket){
    console.log('user connected via socket.io');

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        console.log('Message received: ' + message.text);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    } );

    socket.emit('message', {
        text: 'welcome to chat app'
    })
} );

http.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('server started');
});
```

app.js:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function (){
    console.log('Connected to sockets.io server');

    for(var i = 0; i <250000; i++){
        socket.emit('message', {
            text: 'welcome to chat app'
        })
    }
} );

socket.on('message', function(message){
    console.log('New message ' + counter);
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> A JavaScript runtime contains a message queue, which is a list of messages to be processed. A function is associated with each message. When the stack is empty, a message is taken out of the queue and processed. The processing consists of calling the associated function (and thus creating an initial stack frame). The message processing ends when the stack becomes empty again.

Transmissions over loopback interface are very fast. It's possible that you fill node.js message queue with websocket `message` events even before it has a chance to process the corresponding callback and add `broadcast.emit` event to the queue. Try adding 10-100 ms delay in the client to simulate real network.